# change jquery not working with hide show

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#rbnDoesFatherLiveWithChildNo").change(function () {
        $("FatherAddress").show();
    });
   });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="FatherAddress" style="display:none">
    <div class="formQuestion">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFatherStreetDescription" runat="server" Text="Street Name & Number" CssClass="formLabel"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFatherStreetDescription" runat="server" CssClass="formTextBox"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <div class="formQuestion">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFatherTown" runat="server" Text="Town" CssClass="formLabel"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFatherTown" runat="server" CssClass="formTextBox"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <div class="formQuestion">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFatherPostCode" runat="server" Text="Postcode" CssClass="formLabel"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFaterPostCode" runat="server" CssClass="formTextBox"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <div class="formQuestion">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFatherCountry" runat="server" Text="Country" CssClass="formLabel"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFatherCountry" runat="server" CssClass="formDrpBox"></asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I dont understand why this is not working?

Comment: `"FatherAddress"` should be `"#FatherAddress"`

Comment: Nope that is not the problem

Comment: Where is `rbnDoesFatherLiveWithChildNo`?

Comment: Question above, but should not effect it right?

Comment: @user2633207, It would be good to know what is `rbnDoesFatherLiveWithChildNo`? What wrong with sharing it? because event is bound to it

Answer (score 0):

Erorr in selector. ID should start with`#`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#rbnDoesFatherLiveWithChildNo").change(function () {
        $("#FatherAddress").show();
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

```
    $("FatherAddress").show();
```

which should be

```
    $("#FatherAddress").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using *ASP.Net* generated ID of elements will be different so you should use [**Control.ClientID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it fetches the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

Apart from that `FatherAddress` should be `#FatherAddress`

Change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=rbnDoesFatherLiveWithChildNo.ClientID%>").change(function () {
        $("#FatherAddress").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thnx for the help,  solved it another way:

```
<script>


function showDiv(thediv)
{
    $("#" + thediv).toggle();
}

function hideDiv(thediv) {
    $("#" + thediv).toggle();
}
</script>
```